# Broken words and alignments in LaTeX

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

In LaTeX, how can I stop words be cut at the end of a continuing line? For example at the end of my line there is a word 'ultimately' that once broken changes to 'ulti' and 'mately' in the next line. It is somehow ugly and I prefer not to have it if possible.

Another related question is how I can make the lines FULL-Line which means all the lines in a paragraph have a vertical alignment from the end of the line. Thanks

Comment: For first question: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation  // For second question: fully justified is the default. You have to issue `\raggedleft` or `\raggedright` (usually) to even make the ends of lines not justified. But whatever your cause https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e?lang=en may help. Please, however, consider writing a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to illustrate the undesireable behavior so we know better how to answer your question.

Comment: you're asking for something that may be very difficult to attain.  in order to keep an even right margin, (la)tex tries to arrange the words in a paragraph so that interword spaces are reasonably constant in width.  to accomplish that, often hyphenation is required.  if you wish to avoid all hyphenation and keep an even right margin, issue the command `\sloppy`, or to limit it to one paragraph, wrap that paragraph in a group `{\sloppypar ... \par}`.  you'll soon see why hyphenation is the default.

Answer (score 4):

Your two questions work at cross-purposes. Hyphenation is what gives you the 'vertical alignment' you ask for without making things look much worse.  Compare:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

%\hyphenpenalty=50
\textbf{Default settings.}

\lipsum[3]

\hyphenpenalty=10000
\textbf{Now, no hyphenation.}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: advice: don't put a `%` after `10000`. Leaving a space (from the end line) here helps TeX into ending the integer assignment. It is also stopped by `\textbf` but not until a few more expansions, which with something else where `\textbf` is could ahve aftereffects.

Comment: @jfbu -- Thanks for pointing that out! I tend to overuse `%` because I overuse `C-q` in emacs (it's an uncontrollable compulsion, really!), which is the easiest way to avoid emacs from combining things into one line where I don't want it to.  I'll be more attentive in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I am looking into your solutions but I have found it useful. I will mark the answer as soon as I am conivinced

Comment: ... and by `C-q`, I actually meant `M-q`.